# Chef powershell_script passes but does not actually run script

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, chef-recipe, powershell-4.0

I am trying to automate the setup of a drive via Chef. My chef-client claims the powershell_script runs successfully, however none of the contents of the script were actually run. I have went line by line and can pinpoint which line when included causes this behavior - however I have no idea why it happens, nor do I know to solve it.

Here is a simplified version of the code (I have all the appropriate require statements in my metadata.rb):

```
powershell_script 'SetupTilesDrive' do
    environment ({'driveLetter' => "G", 'drive' => "G:"})
    code <<-EOF
        if (Test-Path $env:drive) {
            Write-Host Disk already exists
            Exit 0
        }

        $offlineDisk = Get-Disk | Where-Object { $_.IsOffline -eq $true }
        if ($offlineDisk -eq $null) {
            Write-Host There is no offline disk; therefore, cannot systematically figure out which disk should be MAPDATA
            Exit 1
        }

        $diskNumber = $offlineDisk[0].Number

        Set-Disk -Number $diskNumber -IsOffline $false
        Set-Disk -Number $diskNumber -IsReadonly $false
        Clear-Disk $diskNumber -Confirm:$false
        Initialize-Disk $diskNumber

        # The following two lines cause this to break
        New-Partition -DiskNumber $diskNumber -DriveLetter $env:driveLetter -UseMaximumSize
        Format-Volume -DriveLetter $env:driveLetter -NewFileSystemLabel MAPDATA -confirm:$false
    EOF
```

end

Once I remove the following two lines:

```
        New-Partition -DiskNumber $diskNumber -DriveLetter $env:driveLetter -UseMaximumSize
        Format-Volume -DriveLetter $env:driveLetter -NewFileSystemLabel MAPDATA -confirm:$false
```

The script will run and perform the pertinent steps, however my drive setup is not yet complete.

Simply trying to write-host the command (on its own) in debug, also does not print out (i.e, the block below)

```
powershell_script 'PrintThis' do
    code <<-EOF
       $diskNumber = 1
       $env:driveLetter = "G"
       Write-Host "New-Partition -DiskNumber $diskNumber -DriveLetter $env:driveLetter -UseMaximumSize"
    EOF
end
```

Anyone have any ideas? Is there some reserved character that I am missing that needs escaping?

I have also noticed the same behavior when using the "-not" operator within a script. As a general practice, I have avoided usage of that operator.

Comment: What happens if you use a normal variable in place of an environment variable?

Comment: I have tried hard-coding all my variables for simplicity and it still doesn't work. Pasting all the code within a powershell interactive console all results in the intended behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a hidden character (in this case, it was â). I simply removed the offending line and re-typed it.